# Unrecognized option "types" | FOS Elastica & Symfony

Tags: symfony, elasticsearch, yaml, foselasticabundle

I am able to create indexes 1 by 1 but my purpose is to have 1 big index with subindexes to search. (I am reproducing an existing app but upgrading dependencies)

Symfony : 5.4*
FOS-Elastica : 6.1
Elastic : 7*

This is my error message and if I change types to properties I have similar errors. I have been trying to switch and indent differently all day:

```
Unrecognized option "types" under "fos_elastica.indexes.app". Available options are "_id", "_routing", "_source", "analyzer", "client", "date_detection", "dynamic", "dynamic_date_formats", "dynamic_templates", "finder", "index_   
  name", "index_prototype", "indexable_callback", "numeric_detection", "persistence", "properties", "serializer", "settings", "use_alias".
```

**What am I doing wrong please ?**

```
#app/config/config.yml
fos_elastica:
    clients:
        default: { host: localhost, port: 9200 }

    indexes:
        app:
            settings:
                analysis:
                    analyzer:
                        fr:
                            tokenizer: standard
                            filter: [ lowercase, stop_fr, snowball_fr ]
                        autocomplete:
                            type: custom
                            tokenizer: whitespace
                            filter: [ lowercase, engram, elision ]
                        csv:
                            type: pattern
                            pattern: '\s*,\s*'
                            lowercase: false
                    filter:
                        snowball_fr:
                            type: "snowball"
                            language: "French"
                        stop_fr:
                            type: "stop"
                            stopwords: "_french_"
                        engram:
                            type: edge_ngram
                            min_gram: 2
                            max_gram: 15
            types:
                # ---------
                # USER
                # ---------
                user:
                    properties:
                        username: ~
                        email: ~
                        organization:
                            type: object
                            properties:
                                id: { index: true }
                                code: { index: true }
                                name:
                                    index: true
                                    type: text
                                    fields:
                                        source: { type: text, index: true }
                    persistence:
                        driver: orm # orm, mongodb, propel are available
                        model: App\Entity\User
                        provider: ~
                        listener: ~
                        finder: ~
```

Comment: I confirm facing the exact same issue, symfony 6 / elastica 6.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was also figuring out how to deal with the same issue as yours, and I do confirm lot of the docs and blogposts out there use the config struture you posted. However when I went back to the v6.1 documentation of the bundle I [found this](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSElasticaBundle/blob/v6.1.0/doc/indexes.md#dynamic-templates):

> **Dynamic templates**

> Dynamic templates allow to define mapping templates
> that will be applied when dynamic introduction of fields / objects
> happens.
>
> **Documentation**

> ```
> fos_elastica:
>     indexes:
>         user:
>             dynamic_templates:
>                 my_template_1:
>                     match: apples_*
>                     mapping:
>                         type: float
>                 my_template_2:
>                     match: *
>                     match_mapping_type: text
>                     mapping:
>                         type: keyword
>             properties:
>                 username: { type: text }
> ```

So in your case a working config would look like:

```
#app/config/config.yml
fos_elastica:
  clients:
    default: { host: localhost, port: 9200 }

  indexes:
    user:
      settings:
        analysis:
          analyzer:
            fr:
              tokenizer: standard
              filter: [ lowercase, stop_fr, snowball_fr ]
            autocomplete:
              type: custom
              tokenizer: whitespace
              filter: [ lowercase, engram, elision ]
            csv:
              type: pattern
              pattern: '\s*,\s*'
              lowercase: false
          filter:
            snowball_fr:
              type: "snowball"
              language: "French"
            stop_fr:
              type: "stop"
              stopwords: "_french_"
            engram:
              type: edge_ngram
              min_gram: 2
              max_gram: 15
      properties:
        username: ~
        email: ~
        organization:
          type: object
          properties:
            id: { index: true }
            code: { index: true }
            name:
              index: true
              type: text
              fields:
                source: { type: text, index: true }
      persistence:
        driver: orm # orm, mongodb, propel are available
        model: App\Entity\User
        provider: ~
        listener: ~
        finder: ~
```